# Save the .xml file using TinyXml

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I want to make an xml file and I am using tinyxml to create it. I am using this code that was already online but it does not save the file.

```
#include "tinyxml.h"

int main()
{
    build_simple_doc();
    return 0;
}
void build_simple_doc( )
{
    // Make xml: <?xml ..><Hello>World</Hello>
    TiXmlDocument doc;
    TiXmlDeclaration * decl = new TiXmlDeclaration( "1.0", "", "" );
    TiXmlElement * element = new TiXmlElement( "Hello" );
    TiXmlText * text = new TiXmlText( "World" );
    element->LinkEndChild( text );
    doc.LinkEndChild( decl );
    doc.LinkEndChild( element );
    doc.SaveFile( "madeByHand.xml" );
}
```

When it executes the last line, the file is not created. I stepped into SaveFile() and there is TiXmlFOpen() method that cannot open the file. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Works for me on Linux.  What compiler are you using and are you on Windows?  You need to delve into tinyxml.cpp and diagnose what's happening with TiXmlFOpen.  It'll either simply call fopen or fopen_s (on windows with _MSC_VER > 1400.  According to the online docs fopen_s may not be available under some circumstances.

Comment: Did you check for errors? http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlDocument.html#348e68faad4a3498f413c51ee9bc321a

Comment: @Matt I am compiling this in VS 2013 on windows. It calls fopen_s(). When you say that it is not available under some circumstances, what alternate method should I consider?

Comment: @Galik yes there are no errors

Comment: @sreeya - I think it's a bug.  In LoadFile change the "rb" on the TiXmlFOpen to simply "w".